# Xcode 7 UI Testing: Screenshots not appearing for Assertion Failure steps

Tags: testing, screenshot, xcode7, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

UI Testing (with Xcode 7) conveniently takes screenshots as the test runs.  These can be viewed using the eye icon on the test results.  However, no eye icon is appearing near to the Assertion Failures, the main area in the test where I would want to see screenshots.

Has anyone else experienced this and found a way around it?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this with the UI Testing implemented in Xcode 7 but I know that you can achieve this with [snapshot](https://github.com/fastlane/snapshot) (I know it's third party but might be a solution for you).

Comment: I have noticed the same issue since Xcode 7.1. Screenshot was working fine in Xcode7.0.1 but failed after upgrading to 7.1

Comment: Even I have the same issue. Did anyone got resolution ?

Comment: Same issue here. I just assumed it was an Xcode bug.

Comment: No resolution yet, but will comment if I find one - still looking.  Recon snapshot may be the best bet currently - though not tried it myself yet.